# Programatically change android setting "Schedule power on and off"

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

Some androids, like the Huawei Honor 8 have a somewhat special feature called *"Schedule power on and off"* which does exactly what it says and looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Read more in [this article](http://webcazine.com/18295/honor-8-how-to-set-your-phone-to-turn-on-off-automatically/).

I want to set this setting programatically... so:

- I guess this is not part of standard android api, so are there vendor specific api-docs somewhere? (e.g. Huawei specific docs)
- Is there a way of listing all available system settings on a specific device? (I've found [Settings.System->getInt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#getInt(android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String)) but that doesn't seem enough)
- Does anyone have any idea to help me continuing my research here? (I'm new to android, any help much appreciated!)

Comment: Have you get any solution?

Comment: Sorry no. This was a side project and it seemed hard so I barely made an attempt :( One other problem was the phone seemed to have a minimum allowed time between power on and off of ~10 min so I couldn't really do what I wanted anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature unique to Chinese Android phones only (apparently it's patented).  Of course it must be possible to code it yourself but I would expect you'd need to read the Chinese developer forums for help.  I have a LeEco Pro 3 and it too has the 'power on' scheduler but this feature is missing in non-Chinese ROMs (e.g. Lineage OS).

EDIT: In addition to all Chinese-brand phones have this feature, it seems that all (?) Huawei phones have the feature too.  e.g. the alarm on the Huawei Mate 10 Pro can power on the handset.

Comment: I confirm. I had a very cheap Cubot phone (Chinese brand) on Android 4.2.2 and it's got this feature whereas my Samsung S4 (Android 11) doesn't...